# Solver for non-linear least squares with boundary constraints

Tags: julia, least-squares

I'm looking for an analog to Matlab's `lsqnonlin` function in Julia.

[LsqFit.jl](https://github.com/JuliaNLSolvers/LsqFit.jl) looks great, but doesn't accept the same arguments Matlab's implementation does; specifically:

- Lower bounds
- Upper bounds
- Initial conditions

where initial conditions, lower, and upper bounds are vectors of length 6.

Any advice would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it does, it's just not explained in the readme (for good measure, here is a stable link [README.md](https://github.com/JuliaNLSolvers/LsqFit.jl/blob/4ecb0ecfa6d02c751e6235ff48204e6f3d5f5262/README.md)).

It is unclear what you mean by initial conditions. If you mean initial parameters, this is very much possible.

```
using LsqFit

# a two-parameter exponential model
# x: array of independent variables
# p: array of model parameters
model(x, p) = p[1]*exp.(-x.*p[2])

# some example data
# xdata: independent variables
# ydata: dependent variable
xdata = linspace(0,10,20)
ydata = model(xdata, [1.0 2.0]) + 0.01*randn(length(xdata))
p0 = [0.5, 0.5]

fit = curve_fit(model, xdata, ydata, p0)
```

(taken from the manual). Here `p0` is the initial parameter vector.

This will give you something very close to `[1.0, 2.0]`. But what if we want to constrain the parameter to be in `[0,1]x[0,1]`? Then we simply set the keyword arguments `lower` and `upper` to be vectors of lower and upper bounds

```
fit = curve_fit(model, xdata, ydata, p0; lower = zeros(2), upper = ones(2))
```

That should give something like `[1.0, 1.0]` depending on your exact data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not a proper answer, but I have had some success in the past
adding a penalization term to the cost function outside the bounds, something like a strong exponential with a step-like behaivour. The downside is defining your cost function manually, of course.