# Converting and applying MATLAB lsqnonlin function in Julia with multiple function arguments

Tags: matlab, julia, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to convert some MATLAB code into Julia. For the largest part this went pretty smooth, but I am now stuck with converting the MATLAB [lsqnonlin][1] function.

After scanning available options, I think that the [LsqFit.jl][2] package with its `curve_fit` function is the best way to go. Please correct me if I am wrong.

The original MATLAB code looks like this, where a function `calc_z` with given lower and upper boundaries (`lb` resp. `ub`) and initial guess `z` should yield optimal values of `z`. `**kwargs` contains all other function arguments required for `calc_z`.

```
z_opt = lsqnonlin(@calc_z, z, lb, ub, lsq_options, **kwargs)
```

Internally, the function `calc_z` computes the error between initial `z` and observed values of z (`z_obs` which are part of `**kwargs`) plus two additional penalty terms which should be minimized to obtain the optimal values of z, `z_opt`.

The question now is how to correctly implement this in Julia. Thus far, I understand that I need something like

```
using LsqFit  

fit = curve_fit(calz_z, xdata, ydata, p0, lower=lb, upper=ub)
# calz_z rewritten in Julia

z_opt = fit.param
```

What is not clear to me is how to deal with the (kw)args required for `calc_z`. Do all `**kwargs` go into `p0`? And is `xdata` equivalent to `z` and `ydata` equivalent to `z_obs`?

It is also unclear to me whether Julia `curve_fit` implicitly computes the sum of squares of the components as `lsqnonlin` does in MATLAB?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you looked at https://juliapackages.com/p/leastsquaresoptim ?

Comment: @Bill, no I haven't! Wasn't aware of this package. Do you have some experience using it, and would you prefer it over the Lsqfit package?

Comment: As a general rule for callback functions; if there aren't any pass-along-args, then you can always just create a closure, e.g. `(x,p)->calc_z(x,p,more_stuff)`. This is also what matlab suggests doing in all their examples for lsqnonlin from what i can see.

From what i can gather, LsqFit.curvefit computes the difference of your function against ydata for the lsq computation (https://github.com/JuliaNLSolvers/LsqFit.jl/blob/master/src/curve_fit.jl#L117) You just can't hide any extra custom penalty terms here, you only get to express the function `f(x)`.

Comment: Hi, thanks @Bill, this package was exactly what I was looking for. @Jannis: I posted an example on it's usage as replacement for MATLAB's `lsqnonlin` here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66502645/using-lsqfit-in-julia/74249216#74249216